# Double.ToString("C") Returning Incorrect Currency Symbol

Tags: .net, vb.net, currency

I have the following code,

```
        txtCaseworkCost.Text = _CaseworkCost.ToString("C")
```

For some reason, the output in the text boxes looks like this,

[image]

With some strange symbol instead of a dollar sign. The local for the computer is the United States so it should be displaying the $ sign.

The control is being used in an AutoCAD plugin, where AutoCAD loads the .Net dll. The strange part, If I use this same control in a windows form application, it works fine with the correct symbols. The incorrect symbol only appears when the code is loaded from the other application.

Is there any workaround for this? I have no control over how AutoCAD loads the dll, so I need to somehow correct the currency symbol from my code. Also, this error also appears in the reporting tool we use, so I am looking for a solution other than manually inserting the symbol.

Comment: what if you try to change the font? What if you change the local currency symbol in the system Control Panel? Nothing permanent but just to see if you manage to get a symbol shown there even for only testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the Thread.CurrentCulture in a plug-in scenario.  The thread is initialized and configured by AutoCAD which may well have changed its default language for its own purposes.  SetThreadLocale() in the winapi.

So if you want dollars then make sure to use the overrides that accept an IFormatProvider argument and pass the Culture.NumberFormatInfo you want.

Comment: I was able to do `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")` and that seems to have corrected the issue, event though the culture reported itself as en-US before.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override whatever the current culture is.

```
Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
txtCaseworkCost.Text = _CaseworkCost.ToString("C", culture)
```

Comment: That would be interesting if it was the AutoCAD assembly causing this issue.  I would throw in a one time check, such as `string culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;` to see what the current culture was returning as first.

Comment: @George, Oddly, the culture claims to be English (United States), but for some reason the property `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` returns `¤`

Answer (score 1):

Set the current culture in your add-in as whatever you like the symbol to appear good in then things are done.